# MongoDB Atlas Search: autocomplete with fuzzy results in constant score

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I am working with the current version of MongoDB Atlas Search (version 4.2.8) hosted cloud.mongodb.com.

My search index is defined as followed:

```
{
  mappings: {
    dynamic: false,
    fields: {
      name: {
        type: "autocomplete"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I am running the following query:

```
db.getCollection("test").aggregate([
  {
    $search: {
      autocomplete: {
        query: "Wassar",
        path: "name",
        fuzzy: { maxEdits: 2 }
      }
    }
  }, {
    $project: {
      name: "$name",
      score: { $meta: "searchScore" }
    }
  }
])
```

On the result the score is a `1.0` for ALL documents in the result set:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("..."), 
  "name" : "Wasser", 
  "score" : 1.0
}
```

Is this the expected behaviour using fuzzy on autocomplete or am I missing something?

Working with type `type: "string"` and `analyzer: "lucene.standard"` in the search index definition and a simple text query, the scoring works as expected.

Sidenote: I expected the fuzzy parameter to be set to the default values as described in the [docs](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/autocomplete/) but it has to be set manually.

Comment: Did you get an answer to your query @peterschrott? I am starting up with atlas search and need to know this as well.

Comment: @AvaniKhabiya, unfortunately not. Atm I am just not using fuzzy search, which is not great but works. I would love to use it. Maybe there is a fix by now? Feel free to keep me updated on that issue.